# How to click on an element using its Id and Value attributes together?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on some button (which becomes enabled after all of the fields are fill in):

```
<div class="savCancelContainer">
    <input type="button"
           value="Save"
           translatekey="ACTVITY_DETAILS_SAVE_BUTTON"
           class="translate" id="submitActivityDetails"
           style="background-color: rgb(0, 125, 195);">
```

The programmers of the web-page have changed it for some reason, and now my code is no longer working correctly (the button doesn't get clicked on):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("submitActivityDetails")).click();
```

I also tried finding it by xpath, with no success.

Is there any way to click the button using the *Id* and *Value* attributes together?

Any other ideas?

Similar pages and dialogs are still working fine...

Comment: by "(that become enabled after all of the field fill in)" do you mean it is loaded into the DOM AFTER fields get filled in?  If its added dynamically, your event listeners won't be bound on page load

Comment: Replace the `\\\` in the comment above with `//`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a xpath which will contain both the attribute:

```
//input[@id='submitActivityDetails'][@value='Save']
```

And Click event can be triggered in the following way:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='submitActivityDetails'][@value='Save']")).click();
```

Lemme know if it helps!

Comment: same thing....the mouse cursor changed to 'click' icon ,but click doesn't perform...(same as before...)

Comment: Is your browser zoom level set to 100%?

Comment: Can you try once : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='submitActivityDetails'][@value='Save']")).sendKeys(Keys.Enter);`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can use css seelctor to perform that action too.

[id='submitActivityDetails'][value='Save']